# TeamCity with AWS cloudformation stuck on AgentService

Tags: teamcity, aws-cloudformation

Followed `TeamCity`'s description of running a `TeamCity` build server on AWS with a cloudformation template. Launched it, it gets stuck at `AgentService` (`Resource creation initiated`). Waited for half an hour, no progress.

Resources tab shows the following:

[image: ![enter image description here]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a tip from a colleague that if you are creating a CF template based service, it may take up to 3(!) hours. Tried again today, after 3 hours it was up and running.

The reason for this is the setup of the ECS, which involves DNS setup for an internet facing service.

Answer (score 1):

(For me) this typically happens if the service cannot be started for some reasons. For instance if the cluster does not have enough suitable instances to start your service or for some other reason.

For diagnostic, check your service in the ECS cluster and there check events and in tasks of your service, check stopped tasks (and reasons they were stopped).